# Open "x" file triggered by incoming email with subject containing "x"

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to open X file (.bat) when an email with subject X arrives. The sender is always the same.

Example: email received from Security with the following subject "balcony alert"; the "balcony.bat" file should open automatically.

I tried to edit the following but it needs to be expanded more, and I have an error in compiling the first line.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

  If TypeName(item) = "Security" Then
    Set Msg = item

    ' If Msg.Subject = "specific subject" Then

    Call Shell("cmd.exe /C /K " & "ChDir f:\" & Msg.Subject & ".bat", vbNormalFocus)

  End If
End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemAdd` event may not fire if you get more than 16 items simultaneously.

I'd recommend handling the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class instead. The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.